# Blurring part of an image

Tags: r

I was going through "The Art of R programming" and came across this piece:

```
# adds random noise to img, at the range rows,cols of img; img and the
# return value are both objects of class pixmap; the parameter q
# controls the weight of the noise, with the result being 1-q times the
# original image plus q times the random noise
blurpart <- function(img,rows,cols,q) {
  lrows <- length(rows)
  lcols <- length(cols)
  newimg <- img
  randomnoise <- matrix(nrow=lrows, ncol=ncols,runif(lrows*lcols))
  newimg@grey <- (1-q) * img@grey + q * randomnoise
  return(newimg)
}
```

My question is about the line:

```
newimg@grey <- (1-q) * img@grey + q * randomnoise
```

How does `newimg@grey` end up being of the same size as `img@grey`. Since `randomnoise` is smaller matrix, how is the `newimg@grey` part recognising what part of the image to blur.

I thought it should be something like:

```
newimg <- img
newimg@grey[rows,cols] <- (1-q) * img@grey[rows,cols] + q * randomnoise
```

Comment: What's `ncols` in that function? Should it be `lcols`? Can you give us a complete working reproducible example? All I get is either `ncols not found` until I change it to `lcols`, and then I get `non-conformable arrays`. Have you got this to work? Help US to help YOU.

Comment: Looking at [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4jL3sfmP1l8C&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22adds+random+noise+to+img,+at+the+range+rows,cols+of+img%22&source=bl&ots=0SkjF1qCIx&sig=ILB-UaRzXoh0mIASnUCpTyz3dSQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HUj1UOenIYmGhQedyoCACg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22adds%20random%20noise%20to%20img%2C%20at%20the%20range%20rows%2Ccols%20of%20img%22&f=false) it seems to be a typo in the original

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easy enough to try running the example as-is and with the recommended correction?  Why post a question before doing the obvious?

Comment: The book prints ncols only. But I guess they wanted to print lcols in which case the the arrays are non-comfortable. Let me check and get back. @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Got the error of non-conformable arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a printing mistake in the book and I have verified that code in the book doesn't work even after get the typo right. I have sent the feedback to the the writer. The correct piece should be:

```
newimg <- img
newimg@grey[rows,cols] <- (1-q) * img@grey[rows,cols] + q * randomnoise
```